# How to Segregate the dictionary key, value and Sum of it values using nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on the nodejs . I have a list of dictionary value. I would like to segregate the value from the dictionary and sum of it. Kindly anyone help me to do this with the example code. I have a list dictionary as like below.

```
      plz_help = [{  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
                  {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
                  {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
                  {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
                  {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
                  {  description: 'Adult', Amount:15},
                 ];
```

I would like to get the result like below example:

```
 plz_help = { 'Senior':100, 'Adult':90, 'Child':35, 'Infant':25}
```

Kindly help me to get the result like this using nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of approaches come to mind. One is to simply iterate over the array and sum things up by putting them into the proper "bucket" in the "result" object. If the bucket is not there, create it.

The second approach is to `reduce` the array. As a benefit of this approach, you could pass an extra argument to the `withReduce` function to configure your reducer.

```
const arr = [{  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
    {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
    {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
    {  description: 'Adult', Amount:15},
];

function iterative(arr) {
    const result = {};
    for (const element of arr) {
        // initialize with 0 if first encounter of this description
        if (result[element.description] === undefined) {
            result[element.description] = 0;
        }
        result[element.description] += element.Amount;
    }
    return result;
}

function withReduce(arr) {
    function reducer(totals, element) {
        if (totals[element.description] === undefined) {
            totals[element.description] = 0;
        }
        totals[element.description] += element.Amount;
        return totals;
    }

    return arr.reduce(reducer, {});
}

console.log(iterative(arr));
console.log(withReduce(arr));
```

Outputs

```
{ Senior: 100, Adult: 90, Child: 35, Infant: 25 }
{ Senior: 100, Adult: 90, Child: 35, Infant: 25 }
```